# Pulling/Pushing database through heroku

Tags: java, eclipse, heroku, pgadmin, heroku-postgres

Hi I have downloaded the pgadmin 3 and connected it to heroku. We have create a table. However, I have no idea how to push this tables that are created to heroku. We have tried https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup but

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE testing --app <app name>
```

keeps returning createdb:could not connect to database template1: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username". What password is it looking for? Also is the username supposed to be my heroku login details

Comment: I've tried every password I have to no avail

Answer (score 1):

When you install Heroku toolbelt on your own machine, you can use `heroku config` to get your database URL, and then enter each element of that URL into PGAdmin. You are now connected directly to your Heroku database. Any change you make (such as adding tables) is a change to your production database.